# Google Sheets - Function to combine cells in a column into two columns with all possible combinations?

Tags: google-sheets, combinations, google-sheets-formula

Can anyone help me write a Google Sheets function for doing this:

Google Sheets example of what needs to be done:

[image: Google Sheets example of what needs to be done]

The first column could be filled with **X lines** with a name in each one.

From that names, the columns "target" and "source" would be filled with *all possible combinations between the names*, **without repeating a pair** (if you already have "Gustavo | Jacinto", you don't need "Jacinto | Gustavo").

I know I can solve this problem using python and other stuff, but I wanted to do this using Google Sheets' functions because it would be faster to get the response I need.

Comment: I worked out another way of doing it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922267/how-to-perform-iteration-over-excel-google-sheets-cells-to-get-pairwise-combinat/47932221#47932221

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(SORT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:A)),",")))&","&
 TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:A)),",")))), (
 UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:A)),",")))<=
 TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:A)),",")))))*
 REGEXMATCH(CONCATENATE(","&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:A),",",",,")&","&CHAR(9)),"(,"&
 UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:A)),",")))&",[^\t]*,"&
 TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:A)),","))))&",)|(,"&
 TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:A)),","))))&",[^\t]*,"&
 UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:A)),",")))&",)"))&CHAR(9)),CHAR(9)))),","))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A2:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(A2:A)),  CHAR(9)))& " "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A2:A&CHAR(9),  COUNTA(A2:A))), CHAR(9))), " ")),
 "where Col1<>Col2 order by Col1", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked really good. **But is there any way to prevent the function from making repetitive relationships like "name1 | name2" and "name2 | name1"?** This would really help.