# How to combine cells into two columns to show all links between the elements in the same row

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm working on a Gephi project where I need to define links between people (who worked with who).

I have a Google Sheet document with names in each row.
Ex:

- John | Mary | Brian | Dave
- Emily | David | Sara

I'm looking for a function that could display me then who worked with who in two columns. This way:

- John | Mary
- John | Brian
- John | Dave
- Mary | Brian
- Mary | Dave
- Brian | Dave
- Emily | David
- Emily | Sara
- David | Sara

If you think Google Sheets ain't the thing and it's possible to do it on Excel, you can send me a suggestion too.

Comment: Please include your attempts.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for the answer, I found it this morning.

All I had to do was edit the code on this Stack Overflow question
[Google Sheets - Function to combine cells in a column into two columns with all possible combinations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771356/google-sheets-function-to-combine-cells-in-a-column-into-two-columns-with-all)

Change the cell range containing your data (for example: A1 to F1), and paste the code in a new cell.

Example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A1:F1)),",")))&","& TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",", ,A1:F1)),",")))), ( UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A1:F1)),",")))<= TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A1:F1)),",")))))* REGEXMATCH(CONCATENATE(","&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",1,A1:F1),",",",,")&","&CHAR(9)),"(,"&  UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A1:F1)),",")))&",[^\t]*,"& TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A1:F1)),","))))&",)|(,"& TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",",1,A1:F1)),","))))&",[^\t]*,"& UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",TEXTJOIN(",", ,A1:F1)),",")))&",)"))&CHAR(9)),CHAR(9)))),","))
```