# How can I create a list of numbers that is like the following?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a list of number like this in Excel, in separate cells:

```
(column B);
1
1
2
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
.
```

If you can't see each number is sequences from one up to the number your on.

Comment: You have tagged vb.net - would a formula solution or VBA be of interest if either is possible?

Comment: That was just a possibility, would rather not use VBA but if that is the only way then so be it.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: I believe the maths is similar to my answer to this question (triangular matrix) - there might be a simpler way of doing it though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922267/how-to-create-all-possible-pair-combinations-without-duplicates-in-google-sheets/47932221#47932221

Comment: With the formatting corrected, I think this is a pretty good question. Would the downvoters kindly re-evaluate the question as it stands?

Answer (score 4):

Using formulas only, no VBA:

In column B:

```
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | =IF(B2-MAX(B$1:B1)<1,B2+1,1)
```

Then fill that formula down

If you want just one formula that stands on its own (without referencing other cells), you can evaluate the [triangle sequence](https://oeis.org/A002260) at term n = ROW() with this more imposing formula:

```
=IFERROR(ROW() - COMBIN(INT((1+SQRT(8*ROW()))/2), 2),1)
```

(The IFERROR part just handles the first term, which attempts to evaluate COMBIN(1,2) )

Comment: Yes perfect answer. I was heading in the same direction, but this is better than my effort would have been.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 1 'the starting row value
y = 2 'the starting column value
z = 9 'the number of entries you ultimately want to make
entryMax = 1 'the max number of this sequence
entryStart = 1 'the start of the sequence

Do While x<=z
entryStart = 1 'reset the value of entryStart    
    Do While entryStart <= entryMax
    cells(x, y) = entryStart
    x= x + 1
    entryStart = entryStart + 1
    Loop
entryMax = entryMax + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the number 1 in B1 then put

```
=B1*10+ROW()
```

in B2 you can drag this down

But you don't state what the pattern should be after B9