# How to create Excel list with data that excludes certain types of combinations

Tags: excel, excel-2011

I have two lists with the same set of data (e.g. A, B, C, D), and I want to be able to create a list of combinations that exclude the same data twice (e.g. A/A, B/B, etc) and reversed  sets (i.e. A/B means I don't want B/A)

I'm using Excel for Mac 2011, if that matters.

**Edit:**

Ideally I would like to use Tables instead of inputting individual data pieces because the actual list is very long

The following tables are named T_TESTA and T_TESTB: [image: table set]

**Edit 2:**

Both solutions presented to me below are working perfectly, but I'm only allowed to pick one. So I'm picking the one based on streamlining an issue that came up for me that's entirely unrelated to the code itself. The other solution is slightly more elegant for presenting the data together in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of formulas I worked out for Google Sheets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922267/how-to-create-all-possible-pair-combinations-without-duplicates-in-google-sheets/47932221#47932221) and translated back into Excel:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,CEILING((2*COUNTA(A:A)-1-SQRT((2*COUNTA(A:A)-1)^2-8*ROW()))/2,1)),"")
```

and

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)+ROW()-((2*COUNTA(A:A)-1)*CEILING(((2*COUNTA(A:A)-1)-SQRT((2*COUNTA(A:A)-1)^2-8*ROW()))/2,1)-CEILING(((2*COUNTA(A:A)-1)-SQRT((2*COUNTA(A:A)-1)^2-8*ROW()))/2,1)^2)/2),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure where I went wrong with your formula: [image](https://i.postimg.cc/52PLPdwF/Screen-Shot-2020-04-26-at-5-39-49-PM.png)

Comment: No, nor am I! The formula in C1 appears to be correct, but I don't know why you're getting those green warning marks in the cells - does the message that goes with them say anything useful? I thought at first there might be something further down column A, but that wouldn't give the results that you're getting. The only other thing I can think of to try would be if you do a screen shot with the cursor in C2, because that's where it starts to go wrong, or ideally share it with Excel online.

Comment: BTW I have created an online version of my sheet: here it is https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtY3C2IFGCfCgYt-cHXov6GUPd4gJg?e=oQCwNK

Comment: Okay, so once I saw how you formatted your sheet, I figured out where I went wrong and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub Kombo()
    arr = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")

    k = 1
    For i = 0 To 2
        For j = i + 1 To 3
            Cells(k, 1) = arr(i) & arr(j)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

The loops are configured to create *combinations* rather than *permutations*.

**EDIT#1:**

In this version of the code we get the values from cells rather than an internal array.  I assume the values are in **E1** through **E4**:

```
Sub Kombo2()
    Dim arr(0 To 3) As Variant

    For i = 0 To 3
        arr(i) = Range("E" & i + 1).Value
    Next i

    k = 1
    For i = 0 To 2
        For j = i + 1 To 3
            Cells(k, 1) = arr(i) & arr(j)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

The results are still displayed in column **A**

Comment: That's awesome! I'm unfortunately super new to macros, so is there a way I can substitute in a table name instead of listing each piece of data individually?

Comment: @AdrianFridge  YES!  just update your original question with the specifics and we will mod the code.

Comment: @AdrianFridge  Good!  I see your edit..............I will update my answer later today.

Comment: @AdrianFridge  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Okay, so if I have n number of rows, I need to input a number of n-1 for the macro to work. That and the proper column letter.