# Calculating the most frequent pairs in a dataset

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, combinations, frequency

Is it possible to calculate most frequent pairs from a combinations of pairs in a dataset with five columns?
I can do this with a macro in excel, I'd be curious to see if there's a simple solution for this in google sheets.

I have a sample data and results page [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15-4CZ2vOgUmFlLLuJlPjEXOWQcksnMD0EbqkdWgJ8d4/edit?usp=sharing) :

Data:

```
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5
6   22  28  32  36
7   10  17  31  35
8   33  38  40  42
10  17  36  40  41
8   10  17  36  54
9   30  32  51  55
1   4   16  26  35
12  28  30  40  43
42  45  47  49  52
10  17  30  31  47
10  17  33  51  58
4   10  17  30  32
2   35  36  37  43
6   10  17  38  55
3   10  17  25  32
```

Results would be like:

```
Value1  Value2  Frequency
10  17  8
10  31  2
17  31  2
10  36  2
17  36  2
30  32  2
10  30  2
17  30  2
10  32  2
17  32  2
```

etc

Each row represents a data set. The pairs don't have to be adjoining. There can be numbers between them.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Most row will end up `1   1 1 1 1`  frequency

Comment: This is a long list, you don't want me to copy and paste all the data here?

Comment: Create a minimal sample.  Starting from scratch is step 1 in [mcve]. Create 4rowx4column data and the  expected output for that data.

Comment: The match must be in the example no need to include all data

Comment: To quote, `Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
…Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself`

Comment: I used a minimal sample here on  this site, the results are correct for this minimal data.

Comment: How is `value1` and `value2` determined?

Comment: Value1 and Value2 make up the pairs that come together often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a combination of pairs for each row using the method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73901481/). Then `REDUCE` all the pairs to create a virtual 2D array. Then use `QUERY` to group and find the count:

```
=QUERY(
  REDUCE(
    {"",""},
    A2:A16,
    LAMBDA(acc,cur, 
      {
        acc;
        QUERY(
          LAMBDA(mrg,
            REDUCE(
              {"",""},
              SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(mrg)-1,1,0),
              LAMBDA(a_,c_,
                {
                  a_;
                  LAMBDA(rg,
                    REDUCE(
                      {"",""},
                      OFFSET(rg,0,1,1,COLUMNS(rg)-1),
                      LAMBDA(a,c,{a;{INDEX(rg,1),c}})
                    )
                  )(OFFSET(mrg,0,c_,1,COLUMNS(mrg)-c_))
                }
              )
            )
          )(OFFSET(cur,0,0,1,5)),
        "where Col1 is not null",0
        )
      }
    )
  ),
  "Select Col1,Col2, count(Col1) group by Col1,Col2  order by count(Col1) desc "
)
```

##### Input:

| B1(A1) | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 22 | 28 | 32 | 36 |
| 7 | 10 | 17 | 31 | 35 |
| 8 | 33 | 38 | 40 | 42 |
| 10 | 17 | 36 | 40 | 41 |
| 8 | 10 | 17 | 36 | 54 |
| 9 | 30 | 32 | 51 | 55 |
| 1 | 4 | 16 | 26 | 35 |
| 12 | 28 | 30 | 40 | 43 |
| 42 | 45 | 47 | 49 | 52 |
| 10 | 17 | 30 | 31 | 47 |
| 10 | 17 | 33 | 51 | 58 |
| 4 | 10 | 17 | 30 | 32 |
| 2 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 43 |
| 6 | 10 | 17 | 38 | 55 |
| 3 | 10 | 17 | 25 | 32 |

##### Output(partial):

|  |  | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 17 | 8 |
| 10 | 30 | 2 |
| 10 | 31 | 2 |
| 10 | 32 | 2 |
| 10 | 36 | 2 |
| 17 | 30 | 2 |
| 17 | 31 | 2 |
| 17 | 32 | 2 |
| 17 | 36 | 2 |
| 30 | 32 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 16 | 1 |
| 1 | 26 | 1 |
| 1 | 35 | 1 |
| 2 | 35 | 1 |
| 2 | 36 | 1 |
| 2 | 37 | 1 |
| 2 | 43 | 1 |
| 3 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 17 | 1 |
| 3 | 25 | 1 |