# How to Calculate frequency of two, three, four and five length pairs in a dataset?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, combinations, frequency

Is it possible to calculate the frequency of two, three, four and five length pairs in a dataset with five columns? I am looking for combinations in the same row, they don't have to adjacent to each other.

I'd be curious to see if there's a simple solution for this in google sheets.

Here is the sample dataset:

```
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5
6   22  28  32  36
7   10  17  31  35
8   33  38  40  42
10  17  36  40  41
8   10  17  36  54
9   30  32  51  55
1   4   16  26  35
12  28  30  40  43
42  45  47  49  52
10  17  30  31  47
10  17  33  51  58
4   10  17  30  32
2   35  36  37  43
6   10  17  38  55
3   10  17  25  32
```

Results would be four different tables:

1. Two pair Frequency

```
Num_1 Num_2 Frequency
10  17  8
10  31  2
17  31  2
etc
```

2. Three pair Frequency (sample data)

```
Num_1 Num_2 Num_3 Frequency
10  17  28 4
10  31  40 2
17  31  54 2
etc
```

3. Four pair Frequency (sample data)

```
Num_1 Num_2 Num_3 Num_4 Frequency
1 10  17  28 4
8 10  31  40 2
9 17  31  54 2
etc
```

4. Five pair Frequency (sample data)

```
Num_1 Num_2 Num_3 Num_4 Num_5 Frequency
1 10  17  28 54 4
1 8 10  31  40 2
2 9 17  31  54 2
etc
```

Each row represents a dataset.

At the end, it could be four separate tables to calculate frequencies of corresponding length pair combinations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see the pattern between your frequency, and given that nobody has responded for 11 hours, I doubt anyone else does either. Simplify and make it easy on us as we're underpaid.

Comment: I can see that the pairs don't need to be adjacent e.g. 10...31 appears in the second row but it doesn't fully explain the results.

Comment: Here is a similar question that was asked earlier. It was only limited to generating frequencies of pair of two numbers. I need something that can do this for tuples of 3, 4 and 5 numbers also.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909283/calculating-the-most-frequent-pairs-in-a-dataset

Comment: @TomSharpe yes the pairs do not have to be only with adjacent numbers. They just have to be in the same row. I am looking for all the combinations. I'll update the description to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

For the two pair frequency (with Num_1 in column I and Num_2 in column J, your dataset first column in A) :

```
=map(I2:I3,J2:J3,
lambda(first_test,second_test, 
countif(
map(A2:A,
lambda(value,
and(countif(indirect("A"&ROW(value)&":E"&ROW(value)),first_test)>0,
countif(indirect("A"&ROW(value)&":E"&ROW(value)),second_test)>0)
)),true)))
```

You can extend the number of tests by editing the first map formula. And for 3, 4 and 5 pairs, you have to add conditions in the AND formula.
The proposed formula does not take into account the order. (10,17) and (17,10) will have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function called `sets` for finding pairs, triples etc. as a lambda in Excel. Here is a Google Sheets version:

```
=arrayformula(
    (
        IF(
            level > maxLevel,
            "x",
            query(
                REDUCE(
                    {"", ""},
                    SEQUENCE(end - start + 1, 1, start),
                    LAMBDA(a, c,
                        VSTACK(
                            a,
                            HSTACK(
                                IF(SEQUENCE(COMBIN(5 - c, maxLevel - level)), INDEX(array, c)),
                                sets(c + 1, end + 1, level + 1, maxLevel, array)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                "offset 1",
                0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

where the parameters are:

```
(start,end,level,maxLevel,array)
```

Here's how it looks for the first line of data looking for triples:

[image]

So now it shouldn't be too bad to repeat it for each line of data using Byrow or similar and get the results e.g. using reduce:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(range,A2:E16,rows,rows(range),list,reduce("",sequence(rows),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,SETS(1,3,1,3,index(range,c))))),query(list,"select Col1,Col2,Col3,count(Col1) group by Col1,Col2,Col3 offset 1",0)))
```

or for pairs:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(range,A2:E16,rows,rows(range),list,reduce("",sequence(rows),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,SETS(1,4,1,2,index(range,c))))),query(list,"select Col1,Col2,count(Col1) group by Col1,Col2 offset 1",0)))
```

where the results do look like OP's:

[image]