# How can I permutate a list with itself 3 times over (or make combinations of 3 from a single list) without duplicates in each combo on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

So I want to make combinations of numbers ending in 5. So I want to make as long of a list as possible - perhaps every number to 1000 or 10000 that ends in 5 etc. Then I would like to make as many combinations OF THOSE NUMBERS as possible. I want the combinations to be combinations of 3 numbers. For example, 25, 895, and 545 as one combination and 35, 765, 235 in another. It is okay if 35, 765, and 235 is one combination and 235, 45, 785 is another combination - i.e. a number can be used in multiple combinations but never more than once in one combination so never 235, 235, 965.

So maximizing the amount of permutations is the most important and I want to do this by removing the instances with combinations of 3 that use the same number more than once.

BONUS: I plan to sum the columns and then search for where a number is used 4 times to reach the same total.

I am using Google sheets. Right now I can make all combinations of 3 lists A B and C and so I copy paste my list 3 times and so I get 25, 25, 25, etc and I want to be able to do that but also to not do that. AND that makes my maximum permutations less.

It also takes more time to look through the data in different ways with the duplicate numbers in the combos.

My combos get close to my goal and so I am wondering if extending the range of permutations would help.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 3):

With formula, you can do it, but it reaches the limit calculations quite soon. You can try with a script, but remember that Google Sheets has its limitations too on amount of cells per sheet: approx 1,000,000 cells

You can try reaching until 1,000. Starting by 5 and steps of 10, it would be 101 numbers until 1,005; then `100*99*98/(3*2) = 166.650 combinations.` Remember to delete other columns:

Then you can have this two functions:

```
function createSequenceArray() {
  var start = 5; // Start value
  var step = 10; // Step size
  var numRows = 101; // Number of rows
  
  var sequenceArray = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    sequenceArray.push([start + i * step]);
  }
  
  // Logging the array to see the result
  Logger.log(sequenceArray);
  return sequenceArray;
}

function createCombinations() {
  var seq = createSequenceArray();
  var resultArray = [];
  for(i=0;i<seq.length;i++){
    for(j=(i+1);j<seq.length;j++){
      for(k=(j+1);k<seq.length;k++){
        resultArray.push([seq[i],seq[j],seq[k]])
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(resultArray.length)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,resultArray.length,3).setValues(resultArray)
}
```

That gets a result like this:

[image]

You can also include the sum:

```
function createCombinations() {
  var seq = createSequenceArray();
  var resultArray = [];
  for(i=0;i<seq.length;i++){
    for(j=(i+1);j<seq.length;j++){
      for(k=(j+1);k<seq.length;k++){
        resultArray.push([seq[i]*1,seq[j]*1,seq[k]*1,seq[i]*1+seq[j]*1+seq[k]*1])
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(resultArray.length)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,resultArray.length,4).setValues(resultArray)
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks - ill have to figure out where to enter the function but i think i can and I like how it is generating it for me and permutating it...

Comment: gimmie a day to test it... or less...

Comment: You have to go to `Extensions - Apps Script` to enter the functions and run it. It will calculate once and "write" the results in the sheet you have open

Comment: ReferenceError: createSequenceArray is not defined

Comment: You've probably copied the second snippet, which is a modification of the second function of the first snippet; copy also the first function of the first snippet `function createSequenceArray(){.........}`

Comment: trying again...

Comment: it makes combinations of 5 numbers but i need combinations of 3 numbers

Comment: 5,15, 25, 45, 225, 625, 895 for example

Comment: actually it gave my combinations of 7 numbers - i need combinations of 3 numbers

Comment: They're three columns, and a fourth one with the sum

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(LAMBDA(x, SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(x, x<>"")&"×"&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(x, x<>"")))&"×"&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(x, x<>""))), "×"))(A2:A), 
 "where Col1<>Col2 and Col2<>Col3 and Col3<>Col1", ))
```

[image]

or directly:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(LAMBDA(x, SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(x, x<>"")&"×"&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(x, x<>"")))&"×"&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(x, x<>""))), "×"))(SEQUENCE(50, 1, 5, 10)), 
 "where Col1<>Col2 and Col2<>Col3 and Col3<>Col1", ))
```

[image]

but be aware that 5-9995 would require 97 020 000 rows which is not realistic within one spreadsheet as that would consume 291 060 000 cells

[image]

Comment: trying to find 8 combinations that sum the same... and of those 8, one number has to get used 4 times, four numbers have to get used 3 times, and four numbers have to get used 2 times... and it is combinations of 3 numbers... so far not looking great from 0-500... so trying to increase range...